# What is the BRU Server Disaster Recovery Procedure?

Tags: windows, sql-server, disaster-recovery, backup-restoration

How do I go about performing a full, bare metal disaster recovery from BRU Server backups?

I have backed up the entire C:\ (including Windows, Program Files etc) of a test machine (using Open File Manager) and want to restore this to a new server.

What is the procedure I need to go through to restore to a clean server using my backup? How does this work with various services such as DHCP, DNS, Active Directory, SQL Server, Windows Registry etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, BRU doesn't support bare metal recovery for Windows, as it lacking the possibility to create recovery media and can't save/restore boot sectors/ partition tables and create NTFS file systems.

The only option for BMR I see is to save the disk layout and boot sector with some disk management program, connect a disk to another computer running BRU client, create the disk layout on the new disk, create file systems and then restore to this disk.

In short: At least for Windows, BRU is a file-only backup solution.

(I might be wrong with this, as I didn't spend a lot of time seeing if I can get BMR for Windows working somehow when I tested it, couldn't find options in the software or hints in the docs).